# Symfony - роутинг

Tags: php, symfony

Изучаю Symfony 4. Делаю первые шаги как показано на официальной странице фреймворка. Но при создании контроллера и роута, ничего не работает. Использую OpenServer (Apache, PHP 7.2).

Выдает такую ошибку:

[image: Ошибка роутинга]

В чем проблема? В OpenServer?

Код контроллера:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Роут:

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

Может нужны какие-то настройки Apache?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route('/lucky/number')
     */
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Нужно подключить Route в use и, например, с помощью анотации(В контроллерах в 99 процентах используется она как и описано в документации Симфони) прописать по какому пути будет выполняться этот екшн(В данном случае екшн `number`).`name` в Route не обязательный, но если нужно это просто как альтернативное название.

P.S. Если не получится, то попробуй перейти по адресу `symfony.loc/app_dev.php/lucky/number`.Так как скорее всего ты находишься в режиме разработки(в dev режиме).

Comment: Использовал то что вы сказали, не сработало. И это тоже symfony.loc/app_dev.php/lucky/number

Comment: И еще нужно добавить аннотации composer require annotations

Comment: На самом деле это странно.У тебя должно всё работать

Comment: У тебя вроде должно работать даже в первом варианте, но проблема явно с файлом роутинга или вообще с роутингом

Comment: В symfony 4 нет фронт контроллеров app.php или app_dev.php . Окружение зависит от переменных окружения, собственно говоря. 

А в данном случае видно что проблема в некорректной настройке  веб сервера, а не с файлом  роутинга. Грубо говоря до symfony запрос "не доходит".

Answer (score 0):

Помимо того, чтобы прописать Route аннотацию, нужно заэксиендить контроллер от `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` помимо этого в routes.yaml подключить контроллеры

```yaml
# config/routes.yaml
blog_list:
    path: /blog
    # the controller value has the format 'controller_class::method_name'
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::list

    # if the action is implemented as the __invoke() method of the
    # controller class, you can skip the '::method_name' part:
    # controller: App\Controller\BlogController
```

Подробнее тут https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-in-yaml-xml-or-php-files

Comment: `заэксиендить`? послайсить или целым писом?